# Big for loop for permutation

Tags: arrays, list, for-loop, append, permutation

I receive 3 integers, "x", "y" and "z". Then a last integer which is "n".

I have to find all possible combinations between x, y and z as in a permutation, but I only need to save those ones where the sum of all values is not equal to n (x + y + z != n).

I have done this trough a big for loop. As you can see, the print output confirms that this logic works, so all the possible combinations are found with any 3 integers you use. Each combination is temporary saved on a list which is constantly overwritten.

I filter the combinations so you can see with the print function only those which sum of the values on the list is not n. However, when I want to save each combination found, it just saves repeated values and it seems that the append method is not working as I need to.

```
# Example:
# 
# Input: x = 1
#        y = 1 
#        z = 1 
#        n = 2
# 
# Output = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1]]

x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

list_x = [x for x in range(x+1)] #numbers from 0 to x
list_y = [y for y in range(y+1)] #numbers from 0 to y
list_z = [z for z in range(z+1)] #numbers from 0 to z

results = []

#Big for loop which makes the permutation
combination = [0,0,0]
for num_x in list_x:
    combination[0] = num_x
    for num_y in list_y:
        combination[1] = num_y
        for num_z in list_z:
            combination[2]=num_z
            if sum(combination) != n: #Find combinations where total sum != to n
                print(combination) #print the combination found
                results.append(combination) #save the combination in a list of lists

print(results) #print the lists of lists
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `combination` is a *reference* to an underlying list, and that's what you're storing in the results (the reference, not the list). This is one of those "a-ha" moments that all Python coders experience, when they start to fully grok the language :-)

Every time you change an *element* of the list (as opposed to the *actual* list), every reference to it seems to change as well, because *there's only one list.*

This makes it appear that you're changing things that have already been set at an earlier time but that's not actually the case.

You can see that in action with:

```py
>>> xyzzy = [1, 2, 3]  # The list.
>>> plugh = xyzzy      # Copies reference, not list content.
>>> xyzzy[1] = 99      # Changes list content (for BOTH references).
>>> xyzzy ; plugh      # Result: they are both changed.
[1, 99, 3]
[1, 99, 3]

>>> xyzzy = [4, 5, 6]  # Makes xyzzy reference point to NEW list.
>>> xyzzy ; plugh      # Result: they are different.
[4, 5, 6]
[1, 99, 3]
```

---

To fix that, you can just get rid of `combination` and just use something like:

```py
for num_x in list_x:
    for num_y in list_y:
        for num_z in list_z:
            if num_x + num_y + num_z != n:
                results.append([num_x, num_y, num_z])
                print(results[-1])
```

That creates and appends a *new* list each time, so changes won't seem to travel back through time.

---

And, for what it's worth, this can also be done with a more Pythonic list comprehension. Using your supplied test data, dummied up:

```py
list_x, list_y, list_z, n = [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], 2
result = [[x, y, z] \
    for x in list_x \
    for y in list_y \
    for z in list_z \
    if x + y + z != n]
print(result)
```

I've split the comprehension across multiple lines for readability but it could just as easily go on one line, and it gives the expected output as per below:

```py
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```